# passing values from Assembly to C

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm

I want to simply pass a variable from assembly over to C and C over to assembly.

The problem is i don't want to use fixed memory addressing (IE. putting the value in a specific location and then using a pointer to access that specific location).

I was initially thinking that i could use registers, but there are only 16 in total! I may have more than 16 values which i want to pass over.

So the next thing i can think of is pushing the values onto the stack. But does this mean i have to use inline assembly to access it in C? something like this:

```
   asm ( assembler template 
       : output operands                  /* optional */
       : input operands                   /* optional */
       : list of clobbered registers      /* optional */
       );
```

Is there any other way to go about this? Can anyone give me a REALLY simple example of putting something on the stack, and then accessing it in C code?

Assembly Noob!

Comment: Write a C function that takes an argument of the same type as your variable.  Write another C function that calls the first function, passing the variable as the argument.  Compile the second function with `gcc -S -O2` -- that means optimize and produce assembly language rather than an object file.  Read the assembly language and see what it does.

Comment: Hmm, i can make a C function and link it in and all. It's the actual passing of the parameter that stumbling me. Every time this program is run, the number of parameters may change - depending on user preference. Is there a way for me to pass an array? But how will i populate that in Assembly? I'm assuming i can access it the way Useless and mentioned bellow? Is this correct?

Comment: I think you're asking two entirely orthogonal questions: 1) _how do I pass a variable number of arguments to a C function_ and 2) _how do I implement that C function using asm for some unspecified reason_. Is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you declare a regular C function, call it from C, and allow the compiler to handle the arguments automatically (according to whatever your local convention is)?

If so, you just *implement* that function using `asm`, and refer to the named C argument list variables directly.

Eg, *using the 68881's fsinx instruction*:

```
float my_fsinx(float angle)
{
    float result;
    asm ("fsinx %1,%0" : "=f" (result) : "f" (angle));
    return result;
}
```

This example is based on the [GCC Extended Asm](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) docs, where you should be able to find some more examples.

---

Now extended, as per the comment, to handle variable numbers of arguments via a simple pointer & count ...

```
float my_fsinx_sum(float *angles, int num_angles)
{
    float result, sum;
    int i;
    for (i=0, sum=0; i < num_angles; ++i)
    {
        asm ("fsinx %1,%0" : "=f" (result) : "f" (angles[i]));
        sum += result;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

No, I'm not sure why you'd want to sum the sines of a bunch of angles either, but hopefully you get the idea.  I haven't tried this, so it's possible the `angles[i]` value needs to be copied out into a local float variable before the asm - try it and see.

---

You could also use a variable argument-list function, but that's a little more complicated. Without more detail on *what you're trying to accomplish* and *what you've already tried*, I can't guess which is better.

*Edit* -- 
OK, now I've seen your comment above, you definitely don't want a variable argument-list function: those still have a number of arguments hardcoded at the call site.

Comment: This is helpful, but what if i don't know the number of arguments ahead of time? I could have 1 parameter, or i could have 10...

Comment: thanks, i meant passing the entire array, but a pointer and count will do just fine as well.

Comment: "sum the sines of a bunch of angles" sounds like [additive synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_synthesis)